# Unable to load URL using AndroidLinkPreviewer library

Tags: api-linkpreview

how are you doing ? I am implementing an android app in kotlin and i would like to display a list of link preview using the following library : `'com.github.OverflowArchives:AndroidLinkPreviewer:0.01'`

I retrieve different links in the adapter and then i pass them as an argument through this function :

```
       binding.linkPreview.loadUrl(link,object :ViewListener{
       override fun onFailedToLoad(e: Exception?) {
           Log.d("TAG", "onPreviewSuccess: Link loading failed the link ====>$link")

       }

       override fun onPreviewSuccess(status: Boolean) {
           Log.d("TAG", "onPreviewSuccess: Link loading succeed ")
       }

   })
```

But i got this error :

```
                                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                    at com.overflowarchives.linkpreview.WhatsappPreview.initView(WhatsappPreview.java:78)
                                                                                                    at com.overflowarchives.linkpreview.WhatsappPreview$2.onData(WhatsappPreview.java:162)
                                                                                                    at com.overflowarchives.linkpreview.LinkPreview$getData.onPostExecute(LinkPreview.java:151)
                                                                                                    at com.overflowarchives.linkpreview.LinkPreview$getData.onPostExecute(LinkPreview.java:31)
                                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:771)
                                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:199)
                                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:788)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Could you help me to figure it out ??